# Breaking up cost string into integer values

Tags: python, string

Say I had a string that was either in the format `$(Integer) - $(Integer)` or `$(Integer)`.  What would be the easiest way to break these up and convert them to integer values?  If the string is in the format `$(Integer) - $(Integer)` take the average of the two numbers.

Example string: `$20 - $40` would be converted to 30  (This is a range)

Comment: What's a number?  Is it an integer, a float, a Decimal?

Comment: @PaulSeeb no sorry that is a range.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski It will always be an integer.

Comment: @HighLife Do you mean an average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> string = '$20 - $40'  #'$20' will also work
>>> x = re.findall(r'\$(\d+)', string)
>>> 1. * sum(map(int, x)) / len(x)
30.0 #convert to int if you want
```